# View | So taxonomy terms plus some links associated with current taxonomy page

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have made a view that show taxonomy terms. What i want is show Taxonomy terms plus some content with.
ex.
I have Auto Manufactures like

```
Auto>
     Audi[taxonomy term :taxonomy/term/1]
     Renault[taxonomy term :taxonomy/term/2]
     Mazda[taxonomy term :taxonomy/term/3]
     [AllNon][content node/1 has field taxonomy ->selected:auto]
```

How i can make a view that shows taxonomy terms and include some content links.
The content links is pages that use a taxonomy field.

Comment: When down Vote please give some info about it. It is General it has been already answered Just to have some clue to update our question Thank you

Comment: I didn't downvote. However, there is no question there, and "So i have a view which finds taxonomy terms and i want to show some content links with it" does not provide much of a clue. I can imagine that someone would downvote this as unclear and too broad.  As it stands, it is unanswerable. I *have* voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly:

- create a view (table) of the content type that contains the taxonomy terms
- add fields as appropriate
- add a  `Content: Link`   field that links to the actual content
- under Table Settings, Group by the taxonomy term

This will however, create multiple rows of the each taxonomy term (one for each node in which it is used).

If your intent was to create one row for each taxonomy term with multiple links (one for each node using that term), I don't believe you can do that in Views.

Comment: @Free Radical - thnx, that's what I get for answering a question before coffee :)